# Node+Jade+Express+Sqlite: How can I add a MiniMap to a Leaflet Map?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sqlite, leaflet

I built a map using Node+Jade+Express+Sqlite. I am trying to add a minimap using a plugin. I added a function to show it but nothing happens.
Here is the code I am using

HTML //here my html code, I use a spin while loading the layers and a function to load the minimap, but the minimap does not show.

According to Minimap's documentation, you cannot use the same layer object again, as that will confuse the two map controls, so, that's why needs to create a new object.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./stylesheets/leaflet-0.7.7/leaflet.css">
<body>
<input value=" + " onclick="showLayer('outdoors','http://{s}.tile.thunderforest.com/outdoors/{z}/{x}/{y}.png')" id="addOutdoors" type="button"> 
<div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 800px"></div>

<script src="./javascripts/leaflet-0.7.7/leaflet.js"></script>

<!-- Spin's include files: https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Spin -->
<!-- MiniMap's include files: https://github.com/Norkart/Leaflet-MiniMap -->

<script>
var map;
var mbTiles = new L.tileLayer('tiles?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}', {
tms: true,
attribution: 'test',
opacity: 0.7
});
map = new L.Map("map",{
fullscreenControl: true,
zoom: 3,
center: [-33.49702,-70.65462],
layers: [mbTiles]
}); 


function showLayer(layerName,layerURL){
    tileLayer = L.tileLayer(layerURL, {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>',
    }); 
    showLoading(layerName,layerURL);    
}   

function showLoading(layerName, layerURL)   { //this function show the spin image while loads the layer
    map.spin(true);
    setTimeout(function () {
        map.addLayer(layerName);
        map.spin(false);
    }, 3000);   
    showMiniMap(layerURL);
} 

function showMiniMap(layerURL){//this function must show the minimap
    var osm2 = new L.TileLayer(layerURL, {minZoom: 0, maxZoom: 13, attribution: osmAttrib });
    var miniMap = new L.Control.MiniMap(osm2, { toggleDisplay: true }).addTo(map);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It looks like there is some confusion in your `layerName` and `layerURL` parameters in `showLayer`, `showLoading` and `showMiniMap` functions. Typos or mistakes?

Answer (score 1):

Besides several other mistakes, the probable one that kills your mini-map is the missing definition for `osmAttrib` variable.

Other mistakes:

- Missing head closing tag.
- Use of `addLayer` with a string as argument, instead of a Layer object.

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ipy91EvabCmKAzAQ4yes?p=preview

Comment: awesome! works perfect! thanks for taking the time!!